# PYTHON: how to print this string using input and loops PYTHON

Tags: python

I am having a difficulty to print this on inverted one but I have a source code in which I can print it on the not inverted right triangle. Can someone help me to fix this?

Source Code:

```
word = input("Enter Word: ")
length = len(word)
for row in range(length):
  for col in range (row+1):
    print(word[col], end="")
  print()
```

Expected Output:

```
Enter Word: MARK
MARK
MAR
MA
M
```

Comment: I havent tried anything code for the inverted and I am having a problem with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply have to change the first range function to change its direction.

```
word = input("Enter Word: ")
for row in range(len(word), 0, -1):
    for col in range(row):
        print(word[col], end="")
    print()
```

Comment: `for row in range(length,0,-1): print(word[:row])`

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for nested loops.

### Text slicing

You can get any value from any container (string, list, dictionary etc) using `[]`

You can get a range of values by separating 3 (start, stop, step) integers by a `:`.

from second value till eighth value get every 2nd value.

```
word[1:9:2]
```

You can get a range of values from the beginning to `nth` element

```
word[:n]
```

See: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-index-and-slice-strings-in-python-3

So your answer can be:

```
word = input("Enter Word: ")
for i in range(len(word)):
    print(word[:len(word)-i])
```